# How do I set test scenarios to run concurrently in Webdriver.io Test Object?

Tags: saucelabs, wdio-v4

For Saucelabs and local Appium testing, we can set the `maxInstances` in Webdriver.io to have our tests run concurrently on multiple devices/instances.

This does not work for test runs on Test Object. Does anyone know if Test Object runs can be configured to run concurrently on multiple devices? If yes, how can that be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer from Abd Sani Abd Jalal mentions, setting `MaxInstances` does work for TestObject as well as Sauce virtual devices. The key is to set your config and capabilities to use devices that are available. Remember that TO uses physical devices, and so a device *must* be available according to your capabilities in order to use it.

Another idea is to consider using [wdio-saucerdc-service](https://github.com/laszlosimity/wdio-saucerdc-service) instead of the standard wdio-sauce-service package. This allows you to connect to TO in a straightforward way directly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `maxInstances` do work for Test Object as well. When setting this value, I would also recommend using dynamic allocation so that it is easier to get devices: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Appium+Capabilities+for+Real+Device+Testing#AppiumCapabilitiesforRealDeviceTesting-CapabilitiesforDynamicAllocationofDevices